# How to change css class of extjs container

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have this extjs container

```
    var cont = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container',{
        cls: 'myClass1',
        id: myId,
        flex: 1
    });
```

How can I change the cls property to 'MyClass2' at run time with javascript/extjs code?

Comment: have you tried to combine `removeCls` and `addCls` functions?

Comment: Actually this is my answer. It works :))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `SENSE.ui.createContainer` make an `Ext.container.Container` base class, then you can use `removeCls` method, as follows:

```
cont.removeCls ('MyClass1');
```

For more info: [Ext.container.Container.removeCls](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-removeCls)